# How to set the value of a React component prop using a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In one of my React components, I track whether a form is dirty by comparing the hash of a data structure to see if it has changed.  Here are the pertinent portions of code (which is non-working):

```
export const CategoryEdit = (props) => {

    // ... 

    const isDirty = () => {
        return (hash(categoryInfo.data) === dataHash);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <SaveBar isShown={isDirty} />
            <p>...</p>
        </>
    )

}
```

How can I make it so the SaveBar calls the isDirty function on every render and dynamically shows/hides itself as appropriate?  Is this possible?

Comment: Add parentheses, like any other function call? (Assuming any of those references actually exist in `isDirty`.)

Comment: You're correct, of course.  I had tried that syntax and it wasn't working, but it turns out that's because of errors elsewhere in my code.  For one, the boolean logic in my isDirty function shown above is inverted.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const CategoryEdit = (props) => {

// ... 

const isDirty = (dataHash) =>() => {
    return (hash(categoryInfo.data) === dataHash);
}

return (
    <>
        <SaveBar isShown={isDirty(value)} />
        <p>...</p>
    </>
)
```

}